# Do neutron stars have enough magnetic pull to move or effect other stars?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, astrophysics, estimation, neutron-stars

Do neutron stars have enough magnetic energy to pull our Sun?

Comment: Pull how? And where? And how would you discern between gravitational attraction and magnetic attraction?

Answer (score 2):

No. Magnetic field is a dipole field, what means it decreases cubically with the distance. According the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star#Magnetic_field), their magnetic field strength tops at around $10^{11} \mathrm{T}$, and their radius at around 10 km.

It leads to a magnetic field of around $10^{-13} \mathrm{T}$ from 1billion km (6 AU). It is *far* weaker as the magnetic field of the Earth (in the order of microteslas).

Maybe in the case of *very close* dual neutron star systems, also the magnetic fields can play role.

In interstellar distances ($\approx$ 100000 AU) the magnetic field is probably below all direct measurement limit.